# ASA 5505 base license and Voice vlan

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vlan, asterisk, voice

My current setup contains a cisco asa 5505 with two cisco sf300-24p switches, the data and voice vlans have been setup on the switches and I've started to setup the needed vlans on the ASA, but it appears I can't create more then 3 vlans (I already have out,in and back up vlans)

Would a voice vlan be possible with this setup or will I need to obtain a Sec-plus license for my asa in order to achieve this?

Most of the configurations I've found use the Security license, so I'm just curious if any one has separated voice and data traffic on a asa using only the base license.

Comment: Hi Charles. Licensing is off-topic per the [faq]. It's a tricky thing to deal with and we don't do it here, since terms and conditions can vary greatly from partner to partner or industry to industry. Your best bet is to call your preferred Cisco VAR and ask.

Comment: I don't think this is really a licensing question - basically your limitation around the number of VLANs is due to licensing, but you are asking whether you can do this with the VLANs you have already.  Is that correct?

Comment: run `show ver` in enabled mode. It will tell you how many vLANs your unit is licensed for. The base model is limited to 3. `show vlan` will list all the configured vLANs too. If this is just a configuration problem please update the question and Flag it to be reopened. For details of licensing, see the "dupe" question for why we don't Answer those. Thank you!

Comment: I know the number of named vlans I am limited to is 3, and I can not have any trunked interfaces, this question isn't really about what the license limits me too, but rather if there's a possible work around to create a voice vlan trunked to my sf-300 switches using the base license, or by other means.